# Navbar Toggler not working

Tags: ee, navigation, bootstrap

TROUBLESHOOTING
Migrating an old blog over using [this templte](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/) Bootcamp 4 and EE
The navbar toggler is working on the .index template but not on the subsequent templates.

[WORKING](http://www.10on12.com/index.php/):

[NOT WORKING](http://www.10on12.com/index.php/notebook/i_like_jazz):

I’m loading jquery.js before bootstrap.js at the bottom of page - so I’ve ruled that out.

Using the same embeds on all templates - so that ticks that box.

Looks like subsequent templates just can’t find the JS folder. Is is an addressing issue?

Anyhow - help appreciated - thanks in advance.
S

Answer (score 2):

You are using relative addressing for the tag that loads your javascript elements: in the page source you see tags that look like this:

`<script src="V2/js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>`

which will cause the browser to try and load the scripts from a URL relative to the current one the browser is at, rather than the site root.

- In your first example (I corrected the typo in your URL for that one) you are looking at a page in root directory, so the browser goes to the correct location for the javascript resources.
- In your second example, the URL being loaded is not the root directory (it is `/notebook/i_like_jazz`) so the browser goes looking for its resources in the wrong directory (presumably `/notebook/i_like_jazz/V2/js`).

You can fix this by either adding `{site_url}` to the start of the paths to load the javascript from, or simply adding a `/` to the tags - something like:

`<script src="/V2/js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>`

HTH

Comment: @10on12 If you found this answer helpful please mark it as "accepted." See the help center for more on accepting answers. https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer